# Graph y = |x − 5|

Tags: calculus

How do I go about graphing a problem like this?

Absolute functions are actually piece wise functions, however, I really don't understand how to set this up.

is it y= x+5

and if so is it no longer an absolute value, instead it is a linear equation.

Please help and explain.

Comment: Chances are good that in your course you are expected to know what $y=|x|$ looks like. If so, you just shift the graph of $y=|x|$ to the right by $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the absolute value is the following $$|x|= \begin{cases} x &\text{ if } &x\geq 0 \\ -x &\text{ if } &x<0 \end{cases}.$$ Let us do the same with your equation. $$|x-5| = \begin{cases} x-5 &\text{ if } x-5\geq 0 &\implies x\geq 5 \\ -(x-5) &\text{ if } x-5< 0 &\implies x<5 \end{cases}$$ In essence, you plot the line $y=x-5$ for all $x \geq 5$ and you plot the line $y= -x +5$ for all $x < 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$y=|x-5|=\begin{cases}x-5\ \ \ \ \text{if $x-5\ge 0$}\\-(x-5)\ \ \ \ \text{if $x-5\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$

So, $y=x-5$ for $x\ge 5$ and $y=-x+5$ for $x\lt 5$.

Comment: This is so confusing to me. The absolute value of |-5| is 5. Five spaces from 0. I understand that. However, how does that relate to what you have done? I don't understand what x-5 if x-5 is greater or equal to zero means in context to my understanding of absolute value.

Comment: $x-5\ge0\iff x\ge 5$, so if $x\ge 5$, then $x-5\ge 0\Rightarrow |x-5|=x-5$. Also, $x-5\lt 0\iff x\lt 5$, so if $x\lt 5$, then $x-5\lt 0\Rightarrow |x-5|=-(x-5)$.

Answer (score 0):

You split it into cases.  For $x \lt 5$, you are graphing $y=x-5$, so plot that part of that line.  For $x \le 5$, you are graphing $y=5-x$, so graph that part of that line.  The combination of them is the graph of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. You need to calculate $|x-5|$ in two different cases: first, when $x - 5 \geq 0$, and second, when $x - 5 \leq 0$.

Alternatively, start with the graph of $f(x) = |x|$ and do what you always do to obtain the graph of $f(x-5)$ from the graph of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For your future exercises, remember:

$$
\   |f(x)| = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    +f(x) & \quad \text{if $f(x)≥0$ }\\
    -f(x) & \quad \text{if $f(x)<0$ }
  \end{array} \right.\
$$